# K8S master etcd missing cerntificates

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, etcd

There are 11 nodes in total, three of them are masters.
Planned to renew certificates in k8s cluster

On one of the masters, the kubeadm alpha certs check-expiration command produces the following

```
CERTIFICATE                         EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
admin.conf                          Oct 08, 2022 10:36 UTC   12d                                     no
apiserver                           Jan 26, 2023 09:47 UTC   121d            ca                      no
!MISSING! apiserver-etcd-client
apiserver-kubelet-client            Jan 26, 2023 09:47 UTC   121d            ca                      no
controller-manager.conf             Jan 26, 2023 09:47 UTC   121d                                    no
!MISSING! etcd-healthcheck-client
!MISSING! etcd-peer
!MISSING! etcd-server
front-proxy-client                  Jan 26, 2023 09:47 UTC   121d            front-proxy-ca          no
scheduler.conf                      Jan 26, 2023 09:47 UTC   121d                                    no


CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
ca                      Aug 03, 2030 22:12 UTC   7y              no
!MISSING! etcd-ca
front-proxy-ca          Aug 03, 2030 22:12 UTC   7y              no
```

There are no such MISSING on the other two master nodes

Please tell me what could be the problem? Will there be problems with renew